# Pass date inside the $axios $get url

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

as I am new to the vuejs, needed some help in syntax. appreciate it if can help.
I have this url:

```
 response = await this.$axios.get('url/john/mychart?start_date=`${newStartDate}`&end_date=`${newEndDate}`',)
```

Also, I am getting these dates from here:

```
  let myCurrentDate = new Date()
    let myPastDate = new Date(myCurrentDate)
    myPastDate.setDate(myPastDate.getDate() - 8)
    let newStartDate = myCurrentDate.toJSON().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, '/');
    let newEndDate = myPastDate.toJSON().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, '/');
```

The problem is the i am not able to get the start date and the end date here:

start_date=`${newStartDate}`&end_date=`${newEndDate}`

Thank you for helping

Comment: what is the problem that you are facing? Please try to elaborate on that. It helps other contributors to understand your question better.

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
response = await this.$axios.get(`url/john/mychart?start_date=${newStartDate}&end_date=${newEndDate}`)
```

note that you must remove the , before ).
OR

```
response = await this.$axios.get('url/john/mychart?start_date=' + newStartDate + '&end_date=' + newEndDate);
```